# .net search algorithm?

Tags: asp.net, search

I'm writing a ASP.net web app where users will be able to add wordy descriptions to a database table and was just wondering if there's some sort of (free) .net search plugin I could use to search through the database. I could write a simple SQL query to do it but I'd rather it be more robust and like a google search.

Answer (score 4):

If your database is SQL Server, then you use SQL Server full text search. It's right there, and has google-like semantics.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) which a port of lucene. Provide search capabilities for arbitrary document (so you can also index database text with it).
But I think you would rather index the html renders of your database entries (which lucene does beautifully).

Comment: Lucene.net is a whole lot of extra work compared to telling sql server to make a appropriate index.